# How do you access and save data from individual cells in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm building a prototype for a voting app. So far, I have a collection view in which each cell contains a person's name, a description, and a slider to select a value on one view controller. On the next view controller, I have a collection view with 3 cells which are supposed to be populated from the previous screen.

I'm trying to save the top 3 people (or cells) using UserDefaults so that I can show them on this second view controller. This is the code I have as of right now:

```
@objc func sliderDidEndSliding(sender: UISlider) {
        var defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        array.append("\(nameLabel.text)")
        defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedStringArray")

        let myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
        print(myarray)
    }
```

I can't quite figure out how to do what I'm trying to do. Currently, the code displays only the name for the slider that was last changed populated across all three cells. This is obviously incorrect and should show three different names for each cell, not the same person in each. My question is, how would I go about saving information from three different cells in a view controller?

Comment: where are you have nameLabel reference? i think you are assigning the nameLabel value in cellForRowAtIndex. Add the delegate and datasource method of the collectionView to understand more about your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. You should not use collection view/table view cells to store data. Ever.

You should use cells and the views inside them to display info to the user, and to collect input from the user. The minute the user changes a value (presses return in a text field to enter the data, taps a button, changes a slider value, etc.) you should collect the changed value and save it to a data model. For collection views and table views, an array, or an array of arrays, is often all you need for a data model. You define a struct that describes the different values for a cell, and then create an array of those structs (for simple linear collection/table view) or an array of arrays (for grid patterns of collection view cells, or for a sectioned table view.)

If you need to pass your data to another view controller, you can just pass the data model object. If you need to persist your data, you persist your data model object (note that UserDefaults is a bad choice for saving a data model. Its intended for saving simple settings like user preferences, not large or complex structures.)